# Is it possible to include / embed a TCPDF document on a html webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf, html2canvas

I am having a problem. I am wanting to use html2canvas to print a PDF (generated by TCPDF) which has been embedded on a page.
Sorry for the very bad drawing, but the PDF needs to be embedded in the page like this.
[image]

Usually for putting a PDF on a page with TCPDF I just an iframe to include the url. But since html2canvas doesn't support printing iframes, that won't work. Using a `$().load();` to try and load it into a div does not work, just creates a bunch of gibberish letters. I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience with this or knows how it might be possible.

Ultimately I'm trying to print the pdf without actually creating a PDF file

Comment: Just share my past experience, one of the ways to tackle the problem is : (1) use Imagick to convert the pdf to jpg (2) embed the jpg onto the page

Comment: Definitely something I'll look into, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, can't comment yet.
Do you want to embed a object like this?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

If so; Let tcpdf create your PDF as a file, ie with

```
$pdfname = 'name_my.pdf';
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$pdfName, 'F');
```

and then

```
echo
'
    <object type="application/pdf"
        data="'.$pdfName.'"
        width="250"
        height="200">
    </object>
';
```

If the error occurs:

```
Unable to create output file
```

Then maybe you struggle with permissions in the directory of your server.